# How to set background-color to the length of the test in a jQuery UI accordion?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am attempting to use a jQuery UI accordion (version 1.9.2) in my webpage.  However, I want to set the background-color property of the CSS of the `p` elements to be the length of the text (similar to an inline look), and I cannot figure out how to do it.  I have tried `display:inline;`, `display:inline-block`, using a span instead of a div, and even setting the width of each paragraph.  All of these either majorly screw with the accordion, or just won't work.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div id="accordion">
      <h3>Sample</h3>
      <div id="accordion-section">
        <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT<br>
        TEXT TEXT TEXT<br>
        TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
        <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT<br>
        TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
        <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT<br>
        TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
      </div>
    <div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#header{
  font-family:cursive;
  text-align:center;
}
#accordion div{
  padding-left: 110px;
}
p{
  background-color:#68FF53;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-indent: -10px;
  padding-left: 20px
}
#education p{
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #75A3EE;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

And the jQuery just sets up the basic accordion, nothing more.

Does anybody have any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, on the p, try: `float: left; clear: both;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use span tag inside your paragraph and give background on span . so background property will be only to the length of text.

```
<div id="accordion-section">
        <p><span>TEXT TEXT TEXT<br>
        TEXT TEXT TEXT<br>
        TEXT TEXT TEXT</span></p>
        <p><span>TEXT TEXT TEXT<br>
        TEXT TEXT TEXT</span></p>
        <p><span>TEXT TEXT TEXT<br>
        TEXT TEXT TEXT</span></p>
      </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#accordion-section p span{
background-color:#68FF53;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This was just the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question,

```
..to set the background-color property ... of the p elements to be the length of the text
```

To me this implies you are trying to set a colour property to a number length?

If you're trying to make sure `<p>` is the length of it's container text then maybe use `white-space:nowrap` which will prevent the text for going onto a new line.

As for setting the background colour then your line `background-color:#68FF53;` should be ok.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.  I was trying to make the background color of each of the paragraphs only as long as the text and not the default block style.